# Uso correcto "related_name" en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

seguramente no he formulado correctamente la pregunta, explico cual es el problema.

Tengo en el modelo:

***models.py***

```
class Muro(models.Model):

    tema = models.ForeignKey(Tematica,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Tematica",
    )
    ...

class Historias(models.Model):

    muro = models.ForeignKey(Muro,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Muro",
    )
    ...


class Comentarios(models.Model):

    historia = models.ForeignKey(Historias,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Historia",
    )
    ...
```

En mi aplicación tengo un muro por tematica, cada tematica tiene sus historias, luego en cada historia quiero añadir comentarios.

Le paso el pk mediante la url y filtro las historias de cada muro, el problema es cuando quiero filtrar los comentarios de cada historia, ya no me sirve el pk, ya que necesitaría el filtrar por el pk de cada historia.

en mi vista tengo:

***views.py***

```
def muro(request, pk):

    cabeceraMuro = Muro.objects.get(pk=pk) 
    historias = Historias.objects.filter(muro__pk=pk)
    comentarios = Comentarios.objects.filter(historia__muro__pk=pk)

    context = {
        'cabeceraMuro': cabeceraMuro,
        'historias': historias,
        'comentarios': comentarios,
    }
    return render(request, 'muro.html', context)
```

Los datos de cabecera del muro todo ok, en las historias del muro todo ok, pero los comentarios se muestran los mismos en todas las historias, no consigo que solo muestre los comentarios que pertenecen a cada historia solamente.

En mi template:

***muro.html***

```
{% for historia in historias %}

<h1>Historia</h1>
...
<p>{{ historia.nombre }}</p>
<p>...</p>
...

<h3>Comentarios de la historia</h3>

{% for coment in comentarios %}
...
<p>{{ coment.comentario }}</p>
<p>...</p>
...

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Estoy estancado en este punto. He leído en la documentación de django sobre [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) he intentado con los ejemplos, pero no lo consigo, al contrario, se me mezclan los comentarios de cada tematica.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Respondo a mi pregunta por haber solucionado el problema.

Ha sido tan sencillo como usar "related_name".

Así en el modelo queda de tal modo:

***models.py***

```
class Muro(models.Model):

    tema = models.ForeignKey(Tematica,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Tematica",
    )
    ...

class Historias(models.Model):

    muro = models.ForeignKey(Muro,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Muro",
    )
    ...


class Comentarios(models.Model):

    historia = models.ForeignKey(Historias,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Historia",
        related_name="comentariosHistoria",
    )
    ...
```

En la vista:

***views.py***

```
def muro(request, pk):

    cabeceraMuro = Muro.objects.get(pk=pk) 
    historias = Historias.objects.filter(muro__pk=pk)

    context = {
        'cabeceraMuro': cabeceraMuro,
        'historias': historias,
    }
    return render(request, 'muro.html', context)
```

Y en el template:

***muro.html***

```
{% for historia in historias %}

<h1>Historia</h1>
...
<p>{{ historia.nombre }}</p>
<p>...</p>
...

<h3>Comentarios de la historia</h3>

{% for coment in historia.comentariosHistoria.all %}
...
<p>{{ coment.comentario }}</p>
<p>...</p>
...

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Espero que pueda ser de ayuda a quien tenga el problema que yo tenía.

Comment: Es importante acotar, que hubieses podido utilizar el related name que Django crea por defecto, el cual es ClassName_set, en este, caso, si tu no defines el related_name, hubieses podido acceder a los comentarios relacionados a cada historia con  `historia.comentarios_set.all` en el template